# Codility OddOccurrencesInArray Problem - Recursion and Python

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, nonetype

I am trying to use recursion to solve the OddOccurrencesInArray Problem in Codility, in which

- we are given an array with N elements, N is always odd
- all of the elements of the array except for one has a total even number of occurrences
- we need to write code that returns the one unpaired value

For example, if the array given is [9, 3, 9, 3, 7, 9, 9], the code must return 7, because that is the only element in the array which is unpaired.

My solution pseudocode/thought process was:

- sort the array
- if the first two elements are equal to each other, remove them and run the solution algorithm again recursively on the array minus the first two elements (after sorting) i.e. if the unpaired element is not found, we keep reducing the size of the array
- if the first two elements are NOT equal to each other, the first element of the array must be the unpaired item

My implementation was:

```
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    if len(A) > 1: 
        A = sorted(A)
        if A[0] != A[1]:
            return A[0]
        else:
            solution(A[2:])
    else:
        return A[0]
```

I keep getting the error message

**Invalid result type, int expected, <class 'NoneType'> found.
RUNTIME ERROR  (tested program terminated with exit code 1)**

Can anyone help me figure out what this means and how I can correct it? Algorithmically, I think my solution is sound, and I don't understand why it isn't returning the integer values as I specified.

Comment: Recursion is overkill for this problem; looping over the sorted array will suffice.  And if you kept track of the unpaired values, you could avoid the sorting as well.

Comment: At a glance you forgot to **return** solution(A[2:]) in the code

Comment: @ScottHunter Anything other than xor-ing all the numbers together is overkill.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach altogether. A recursive approach is not incorrect, however repeated calls to `sorted` is highly inefficient, especially if the input is significantly large.

```py
def solve(t):
  s = set()
  for v in t:
    s.add(v) if v not in s else s.remove(v)
  return list(s)
```

```py
input = [9, 3, 9, 3, 7, 9, 9]
solve(input)
```

We can visualize `s` over the course of the evaluation -

```py
{}     # <- initial s
{9}    # <- 9 is added
{9,3}  # <- 3 is added
{3}    # <- 9 is removed
{}     # <- 3 is removed
{7}    # <- 7 is added
{7,9}  # <- 9 is added
{7}    # <- 9 is removed
```

The finally `list(s)` is returned converting `{7}` to `[7]`. To output the answer we can write a simple `if/elif/else` -

```py
unpaired = solve(input)

if (len(unpaired) < 1):
  print("there are no unpaired elements")
elif (len(unpaired) > 1):
  print("there is more than one unpaired element")
else:
  print("answer:", unpaired[0])
```

Another option is to have `solve` return the first unpaired element or `None` -

```py
def solve(t):
  s = set()
  for v in t:
    s.add(v) if v not in s else s.remove(v)
  for v in s:
    return v          # <- immediately return first element
```

```py
answer = solve(input)

if answer is None:
  print("no solution")
else:
  print("the solution is", answer)
```

Answer (score 25):

## Another Python solution 100%

There is another solution where we can use XOR logic.

First Let's remember together what does XOR mean:
[image: XOR Table]

We can recognize that if we have for **Input A** and **Input B** the same bit then, XOR Output will be **zero**.

Also, if we take the bit XOR of any number with zero that definitely give **the same number** because the bits of the number will result in the same bits which means the same number.

Now, to solve the problem with the XOR logic, we start by defining a number that will hold the result of the XOR output each time, so first, we start with **zero** and I said earlier that **zero** with any number gives the same number.

But if we get a different number next time, the XOR result will be some **unknown number**.

In the end, for sure the number that did not pair will be returned.

Since a solution like this will be possible with only **one loop**, then we need to loop through all the elements and if we do **break** at some point, the result of the XOR would be some number we do not need!

So we need to make sure that we loop through the whole array **once** and then because of the fact that bit XOR of the same number would return zero.
So that, we remain at the end with the number that is **unpaired** with anything.

Detected time complexity:
**O(N) or O(N*log(N))**

```
def solution(A): 
     
    num = 0

    for i in range(len(A)): 
        num = num ^ A[i]        
         
    return num
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything from your recursive call, which means you are returning `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def solution(A):
    cloned = []
    A.sort()
    if len(A) > 1:
       for itr in A:
          if itr in cloned:
             itrindex = cloned.index(itr)
             cloned.pop(itrindex)
          else:
             cloned.append(itr)
    else:
        return A[0]

    return cloned[0]
```

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow, Stephen. I think it is better to enhance your answers with some explanation so that others can understand the logic behind your solution!

Answer (score 0):

It has something simple like this using php array functions, it had 100% score at codility, thought it might help if python has some array functions like this.

```
function solution($a){
      $result  = array_count_values($a);
     $result = array_filter($result , function($a){
           return ($a  % 2) && 1;
     });
    return key($result);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple ways but the performance just doesn't get better!

```
def solution(A):    
    for i in set(A):
    if A.count(i) == 1:
        return i
```

This just gives me a 25% perf score. However, I tried other way also.

```
from collections import Counter
def solution(A): 
    c = Counter(A)
    final = [k for k, v in c.items() if v == 1]
    return final[0]
```

This could be a solution but the performance score is just 50%. Not sure what makes it 100%. Please post if you get 100% perf for this challenge in Codility.

Edit1:

```
def solution(A):
    A.sort()
    A.append(-1) #Just to make list even and run till last but not match with existing integers
    for i in range(0,len(A),2):
        if A[i]!=A[i+1]:
            return A[I]
```

This got me a 100% perf score. Ref:CodeTrading (YouTube)

Answer (score 0):

I've got 100% performance with this solution

```py
from collections import Counter

def solution(A):
    counter = Counter(A)
    for k,v in counter.items():
        if v % 2 == 1:
            return k
    return None
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My idea was try to implement a left and right reading with memmonization inside another array of the elements already tested,

```py
def solution(A):
    # Implement your solution here
    j=len(A)-1
    tested=[]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] not in tested and A.count(A[i]) % 2 != 0:
            return A[i]
        else:
            tested.append(A[i])
        if A[j] not in tested and A.count(A[j]) % 2 != 0:
            return A[j]
        else:
            tested.append(A[i])
    return None
```

I got 66%, 100% correctness, and 25% performance.

I have been trying to implement a binary search without success to reduce the number of readings, but it is blocked.

Answer (score -1):

```
from functools import reduce
def solution(A):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x ^ y, A)
```

The XOR is associative therefore `a^b^a^c^b^d^c = (a^a)^(b^b)^(c^c)^d = d`